# Why Lord Shiva has two scorpions on his ears?

Tags: shiva, puranas

There are two scorpions on the ears of lord Shiva. Who they are & who cursed  them?

I would be obliged if you could answer my query and this is my first attempt.

Comment: Alampur jogulamba is one ofthe shakthipeethas. She has a scorpion,lizard in her head. Has a skull in the hand. But I don't know about shiva having them. Please post an image.

Comment: This question was asked in a Bhagwat purana quiz by a bunch of shastri(pundit)

Comment: @kmlchhtr Where was that quiz conducted ? On TV channels?

Comment: it was individually conducted in a village in west bengal

Comment: @kmlchhtr Was the quiz conducted as part of a satsang by a special group ?There is one organization which is known to promote lies and false ideas which are not based on Scriptures..

Answer (score 5):

This is partial answer.

> There are two scorpions on the ears of lord Shiva. Who are they?

Serpents **Kambala** and **Asvatara** are Lord Shiva's earrings.

**[Chapter 34](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-i/chapter-34/topic-1), Kedarakhanda- Maheswarakhanda of Skanda Purana** mentions names of all serpents which are present on Lord Shiva as ornaments.

Narada goes to Kailasa and sees the Lord Shiva as follows:

> 33. Similarly Sambhu, the lord of the three worlds, was seen by Narada, as being served by Suras and Asuras. The lord had the lustre
>     of pure gold.
>
> 34-35. His lotus-like feet were served by Sankha, the excellent
> serpent. He was served by the following serpents: Dhrtarastra, Takşaka
> in particular, the great serpent Padma and Šeșa in particular. He was
> continuously served by other excellent serpents. Vasuki had become a
> necklace of great lustre and was retained in the neck.
>
> 36. **Kambala and Asvatara were his perpetual ear-rings.** Other excellent serpents were ensconced at the root of his matted hair.
>
> 37-44. He was covered by serpents of many colours and types, e.g.
> Taksaka, Kulika, Sankha, Dhrtarastra of great lustre, Padma, Dambha,
> Sudambha, Karāla, Bhīşaņa-these and many other serpents formed parts
> of Hara who was the most worthy of being worshipped in the three
> worlds.

These two Serpents live in **Sutala loka**. Sutala loka is one of the nether worlds below earth. Seven Nether lokas are Atala, Vitala, **Sutala**, Talaatala, Rasatala, Mahaatala and Paatala.

**[Chapter 20](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/the-brahmanda-purana/vol-i/chapter-20/topic-1), Anusanga of Brahmanda Purana** says

> 20b-25a. In the nether-world Sutala, O Brähmanas,  are the abodes of
> the following, viz. the city of the first lord of the Daityas and
> Räksasas i.e. Of Mahäjambha, the palace of  Hayagriva, Krsna and
> Nikumbha, the city of the Daitya named  Sankha and that of Gomukha,
> the abode of the demons Nila,  Megha and Kathana, the abode of
> Kukupäda and **that of Mahosnisa, the city of Kambala the serpent and
> that of Asvatara** and the city of Taksaka the noble-souled son of
> Kadru.  Thus there are, O Brähmana, thousands of cities belonging to
> the serpents, Dänavas and the Räkshasas in the nether-world of pale
> white coloured soil.

If you are wondering how could those serpents live at two places simultaneously, divine amsas of them could stay with Shiva forever while physically they could live in Sutala loka.